# How to parse a particular attribute name from an XML file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the `.gxl` file below, I want the content with the attr name `"chem"`.
How can I get that?

I have tried this:

```
 for node in tree.findall(".//node/attr/int"):
```

but it's giving the one with attr name `"charge"` as well.

```xml
<gxl>
<graph id="molid164" edgeids="false" edgemode="undirected">
<node id="_1">
<attr name="symbol">
<string>C  </string>
</attr>
<attr name="chem">
<int>1</int>
</attr>
<attr name="charge">
<int>0</int>
</attr>
<attr name="x">
<float>3.7321</float>
</attr>
<attr name="y">
<float>0.25</float>
</attr>
</node>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If tree is ElementTree, you can use xpath.

```
for node in tree.findall(".//node/attr/int[@name='chem']")
```

Comment: I think the correct expression is `for node in tree.findall(".//node/attr[@name='chem']/int")`